# C#: Дизайн прозрачной формы (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, form, ui, design

[image: Normal label, textbox and button]

[image: Not normal label, textbox and button]

Есть некоторые проблемы с дизайном прозрачной формы:

1. Я не могу перемещать форму за саму форму, т.к. она прозрачная
2. Я могу перемещать форму за буквы, но не за сам лейбл, что не очень удобно
3. Если текст светлый, он искажается на светлом фоне
4. Если текст тёмный, он искажается на тёмном фоне

Если мне тут помогут, я проект с исправленным дизайном, может кому-то это понадобится.

```
public partial class BlurForm : Form
{

    public BlurForm()
    {
        this.EnableBlur();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(103, 65, 114);
        TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(103, 65, 114);
        InitializeComponent();
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
}

public static class WindowExtension
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static internal extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);

    public static void EnableBlur(this Form @this)
    {
        var accent = new AccentPolicy();
        accent.AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND;
        var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);
        var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);
        var Data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData();
        Data.Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY;
        Data.SizeOfData = accentStructSize;
        Data.Data = accentPtr;
        SetWindowCompositionAttribute(@this.Handle, ref Data);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
    }

}
enum AccentState
{
    ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
    ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
    ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
}

struct AccentPolicy
{
    public AccentState AccentState;
    public int AccentFlags;
    public int GradientColor;
    public int AnimationId;
}

struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
{
    public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
    public IntPtr Data;
    public int SizeOfData;
}

enum WindowCompositionAttribute
{
    WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
}
```

Comment: Тут как бы нужно писать на русском. Неспроста же сайт так называется.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом форма? Напишите более корректно

Comment: вы бы лучше код этой формы привели, пока лично я вижу две картинки, одна чуть лучше, другая чуть хуже. Что вы понимаете под прозрачностью формы? Как добиваетесь этой прозрачности? Как должно работать по вашему?

Comment: Что касается искажения цвета - это неизбежно, чисто технически решить можно, но патч для человеческого глаза вы вряд ли сделаете, а часть видимых искажений именно из-за особенностей нашего восприятия.

Comment: rdorn, в том же фотошопе текст на любом фоне выглядит нормально, т.е. без "битых" пикселей по краям. Не думаю, что для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно делать патч для глаз. Ни одно решение мне не помогло. Например, предлагали использовать при отрисовке текста System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias.

Comment: В фотошопе текст не вырезается из готового изображения, а сам по себе является изображением в отдельном слое. Я имел ввиду немного другие искажения, которые также делают текст не читаемым, даже без учета рваных краев. В любом случае без вашего кода отрисовки формы дальнейшее обсуждение не имеет смысла, извините, даром телепатии не обладаю.

Comment: rdorn, держи код: https://pastebin.com/c2svTaCG

Comment: Добавляйте @ перед ником того, к кому обращаетесь, за исключением авторов сообщений, в этом случае система отправляет уведомление пользователю о вашем ответе. По вопросам: неровности по краям появляются как раз из-за сглаживания. Я вижу только один вариант, так подобрать цвет фона и текста, чтобы разница между ними была минимальна. Над остальным пока думаю

Comment: @rdorn не получится подобрать цвет фона или текста, поскольку форма является прозрачной и по ходу перемещения цвет фона за ней меняется, т.е. это может быть, например, картинка на рабочем столе или какой то сайт, да что угодно. И цвета могут быть любые. В другой теме мне написали, что с помощью GDI+ это невозможно сделать, но возможно сделать в WPF (для этой платформы я кстати нашёл рабочее решение, но там используется класс, который работает только с WPF и не подходит для Windows Forms). Есть ли варианты сделать это в Windows Forms хотя бы с использованием сторонних библиотек?

Comment: получится, цвет фона формы и реальный фон - разные вещи

Comment: Все таки код лучше прямо в вопрос добавить, тут так принято. Картинку можно оставить только нижнюю, на ней хорошо видно проблему со шрифтом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть некоторые проблемы с дизайном прозрачной формы: 
>   1. Я не могу перемещать форму за саму форму, т.к. она прозрачная 
>   2. Я могу перемещать форму за буквы, но не за сам лейбл, что не очень удобно

Это связано с тем, что по-умолчанию форму можно перемещать только за шапку, но у вас она отключена (`FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`). Поэтому нужно добавить обработчик вручную. Например так:

```
public BlurForm()
{
    this.EnableBlur();
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    BackColor = Color.FromArgb(103, 65, 114);
    TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(103, 65, 114);
    InitializeComponent();
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    //это не обязательно писать явно, можно сделать мышкой в дизайнере
    MouseDown += BlurForm_MouseDown;
    MouseMove += BlurForm_MouseMove;
}

private Point _startPosition;

private void BlurForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _startPosition = e.Location;
}

private void BlurForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        Location = new Point(Location.X + e.X - _startPosition.X, Location.Y + e.Y - _startPosition.Y);
}
```

Также, полезно подписаться на аналогичные события для `Label` и других контролов, и обрабтать их соответствующим образом. Только нужно помнить, что в аргументах события мыши передаются координаты относительно контрола в котором событие произошло, поэтому требуется пересчитать их в соответствующие координаты. Но в предложенном варианте это не требуется, т.к. все задается в относительных величинах.

> 3. Если текст светлый, он искажается на светлом фоне
> 4. Если текст тёмный, он искажается на тёмном фоне

Тут причина довольно простая. Собственно сглаживание шрифта и вносит искажения которые вы видите. Чтобы искажения стали невидимыми, нужно сделать цвет текста и фона почти одинаковым, допустим если цвет фона формы (103, 65, 114) то цвет текста, например (103, 65, 115). Это позволит отработать фильтру прозрачности по заданному цвету и при сглаживании не будет резкого перепада цвета, из-за которого и появляется неприятная рваная граница.

Важно. Цвет фона прозрачной формы остается тем же, каким его задали, несмотря на прозрачность. Это легко проверить: отключаем в настройках Windows оформление Aero, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> и вставляем буфер в Paint. Сглаживание шрифта происходит цветами в промежутке между цветом шрифта и цветом фона формы, а то что просвечивает сквозь форму значения не имеет.

Comment: Возможно, я чего то не понял, но какой бы я не подбирал текст, эти рваные границы остаются. По поводу прозрачности мыши по подробнее, пожалуйста. И если возможно, сделайте пример, в котором этих рваных границ не будет видно на любом фоне.

Comment: @Behavior по поводу мыши не торопитесь. А по поводу цветов, возьмите пример из ответа и попробуйте. Естественно темный шрифт на светлом фоне будет более зубчатым - это не исправить.

Comment: Когда я делаю скриншот прозрачной формы, то в пейнт попадает пространство, которое за ней находится, но никак не сама форма без прозрачности.

Comment: @Behavior Еще раз - Alt + PrtScrn. Просто PrtScrn берет экран - это не тоже самое. ну и естественно форма в это время должна быть в фокусе

Comment: Форма в фокусе, нажал нужные клавиши, результат тот же. Может, мы чего то не знаем?) http://i.imgur.com/V2aYx8K.png

Comment: @Behavior странно, хотя может это из-за того, что у меня Aero выключен. Сейчас проверю

Comment: Кстати, если из кода убрать TransparencyKey, то форма всё равно будет размытой и прозрачной, но рваных краёв не будет. Но она станет ярче процентов так на 50. Как это объяснить?

Comment: @Behavior ну это совсем просто - это особенность интерфейса Aero. Вроде настраивается, но в любом случае это системная настройка, к программе отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Behavior по поводу мыши кстати, все нормально. Реагирует на события как положено, так что либо вы дали не весь код, либо неправильно написали обработчик перетаскивания. Таскается прекрасно и за форму и за лейбелы прозрачные

Comment: А какой обработчик вы используете?

Comment: @Behavior дополнил

Comment: Хм...почему то не работает. Так же не работает другой пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable

Comment: @Behavior значит что-то где-то не так подставили. Я собственно для тестов использовал именно ваш код + 2 label с разными цветами текста.

Comment: Можете загрузить проект на GoogleDrive и дать ссылку? Возможно, я что то упустил.

Comment: @Behavior https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwMcxrjnAjsWaTdlckZONEg3a28

Comment: Хм...всё ещё не перемещается. Мб проблема в Windows 10?

Comment: @Behavior проверил на Win10 у коллеги, все работает как задумано. Даже не знаю что еще может быть не так с вашей стороны.В любом случае мне было бы интересно узнать причину.