# Прозрачный UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

И так проблема заключается в том что у меня есть UserControl на котором есть кнопка, у юзер контрола фон - `transparent` у кнопки тоже, но при добавлении его на форму фон почему-то белый... Я пробовал писать `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` В конструкторе, но не помогло. Помогите ребят!

Comment: Ох перешли бы вы на WPF, все вопросы по дизайну разом бы отпали...

Comment: некоторые фишки работают только с включенным Аэро, если речь про Win 7-10. Примеры работы с прозрачностью и решение некоторых проблем есть тут:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359642/5796587), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688146/198316), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/484198/198316)

Comment: ну и кроме `SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true)` нужно еще задать фильтр цвета, для относительно которого эта прозрачность считается `TransparencyKey`, рабочий пример в вопросе по второй ссылке.