# Как сделать прозрачную заставку Windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать прозрачную заставку Windows forms?
Собственно и весь вопрос.
Надо чтоб при запуске программы на несколько секунд появлялась картинка png с прозрачным фоном

---

Кто нибудь знает как избавиться от этого белого контура при TransparencyKey=Control?

---

Собственно вот скрин:

Comment: Как у Photoshop?

Comment: Ну типа того\\\

Comment: Это называется Splash screen если что. P.S. Если вы делаете что то подобное, то разрабатываете дизайн приложения и тут мой совет - перейдите на WPF...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7955663/4928642

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688146/198316) вопрос более общий, но в ответе есть рекомендации, как избавиться от искажения цвета при сглаживании. Дубль или нет - решайте сами.

Answer (score 1):

1. Чем вообще является эта самая белая окантовка? Это полутона черного. Собственно они у тебя **не** цвета, который должен быть прозрачным.

   Решение: Тебе нужно картинку всунуть БЕЗ сжатия и без полутонов. Раз уж картинка у тебя одноцветная, переведи картинку в палитру из 2х цветов в фотошопе, потом сохраняй, а потом уже используй у себя в программе. Белая окантовка исчезнет.
2. Создаешь форму PictureBox и задаешь цвет прозрачности(в твоем случае, на сколько я понимаю -- белый), BorderStyle - None
3. Показываешь эту форму 1 секунду, потом закрываешь и открываешь следующую форму уже с самой прогой :)

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь отдельную форму с PictureBox, с FormBorderStyle None и с TransparencyKey заданным на цвет фона формы. В PictureBox ставишь свою картинку для заставки. А потом пишешь код, который спустя какое-то время откроет твою основную форму и закроет заставку. Как-то так

Comment: ну фон то все равно белый остается

Comment: Ну, так в TransparencyKey задай цвет этого фона

Comment: вроде получается,но почему то получается какой то некрасивый белый контур